# Google Compute Engine: Do I get charged for GPU on a stopped instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine

On [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/stop), it says that:

> Stopped instances do not incur per-minute, virtual machine usage
>   charges while they are stopped, but any resources that the virtual
>   machine is using, such as persistent disks and static IP addresses,
>   will continue to be charged until they are deleted

Does the GPU attached to the instance count as "resources the vm is using"? Or is it a part of the VM?

Comment: "persistent disks and static IP addresses" - seems clear.

Comment: it says "SUCH AS persistent disks and static IP addresses", so more than just those. Does it include GPU or not?

Comment: Read the agreement and contact Google to ask.  GPUs are clearly not storage.

Answer (score 16):

The documentation page has been updated and now explicitly mentions:

> GPUs are not charged when an instance is stopped. A GPU attached to a
>   stopped instance will not count against your project quota.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance

Comment: For some reason the docs linked to here no longer seem to mention the quoted text. I don't think anything has changed though. Just annoying not to have an explicit assurance.

Comment: Yes the linked docs no longer mention this, however it is mentioned in the comparison table on the "VM Instance Lifecycle" page:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle#comparison_table

Answer (score 8):

Using the [Google Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#) I put in 2 identical instances, both with GPU's, one running for 24 hours a day, the other running for 12 hours a day. The GPU price was halved.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=7bfaa912-f9ab-4ad4-bdda-02dd04d5aaca) is the estimate I created.

Although this is not conclusive for the stopped v's deleted instance question, when you add persistent disks into the estimate, the cost is NOT reduced when you reduce the number of hours that the instance is running for.

I strongly suggest that GPU's are not charged for when your instance is in a stopped state.